# how to make "typeof obj[keyof typeof obj]" generic

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type with all values from object, structured like this:

```js
const MyBar = {
  Benchpress : 1,
  Squats : 2
} as const;
```

I tried to create a type, but it didn't work:

```js
type EnumLike<T extends {}> = (obj: T) => typeof obj[keyof typeof obj];
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```js
type BarKeys = EnumLike(MyBar); // BarKeys 1|2
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use type as a function, instead consider using the following type that returns all values of an object. Also, make sure that you are using `object` as constraint, not `{}`. You can read more about them in [here](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2023/01/23/typescript-sets/):

```
type ValueOf<T extends object> = T[keyof T];
```

Testing:

```
type BarKeys = ValueOf<typeof MyBar>; //  1 | 2
```